# Multiple values variable inside Find "contains"

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

My variable returns multiple values, separated by comma or, after JSON stringify, by line breaks.

**Example:**

```
return mail // email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@live.com;
```

**After Stringify:**

```
var mail =
  ["email1@gmail.com",
  "email2@gmail.com",
  "email3@live.com"]
```

With those 3 emails, I have another variable that uses `find` inside my data, like:

```
$("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('" + mail + "')" ).siblings("td:nth-child(3)").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

**My data:**

```
<table id="dat">
    <tr> <td>email3@live.com</td> <td>Name</td> <td>Project</td> </tr>
</table>
```

This works for a single string variable (if I use `mail` only for "email3@live.com", ignoring the other two emails). Is this possible to do if my variable has more than one value?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to iterate over your mail Array using the `forEach` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach : `mail.forEach(function(m) { $("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('" + m + "')" /*...*/ });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mail` variable is an Array, you have to loop over each entry:

```
var mail =
  ["email1@gmail.com",
      "email2@gmail.com",
      "email3@live.com"]

mail.forEach(function(m) {
    // now 'm' contains your email string
    var result = $("#dat").contents()
        .find("td:contains('" + m + "')" )
        .siblings("td:nth-child(3)")
        .map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
    // do something with result
}
```

You may also want to introduce a variable to store the results

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the CSS ":contains()" selector does not provide matching against lists. You have to cycle over both: your td elements and emails in list.
This has already been shown in another answer.

However I would advice you to not use the CSS ":contains()" selector at all since it has been removed in the CSS3 spec and may cause additional calculation load (since only jQuery couldnot use browser implementation):

```
var mail = ["email1@gmail.com",
            "email2@gmail.com",
            "email3@live.com" ]

$("#dat tr").each(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).first().html(), mail) {
        $(this,':nth-child(3)').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Couldn't make this work here. Thanks for your advice, René!